# Algorithm: for G = (V,E), how to determine if the set of edges(e belong to E) is a valid cut set of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, theory

Given a subset of edges of a graph G = (V,E), how can we  check whether it is a valid cut-set of the graph or not?
Note: A cut is a partition of the vertices of a graph into two disjoint subsets. So, cut-set of the cut is the set of edges whose end points are in different subsets of the partition.
I am interested to find an algorithm for this problem

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm would be to remove the suspected cut-edges from the graph, and see if you can still get from a node of a removed edge to its counterpart. If you still can, it was not a full cut. So if you remove E2 which had nodes A and D, you can use breadth first search from A and see if you ever get to D. It should be linear in space requirements and complexity since we store all the nodes we've visited so we don't backtrack and visit any node twice.
This wiki page has some nice pictures that might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: @Josh Thanks, one doubt, in a square graph, can I have a cut-set of size 3 (3 edges)?

Comment: I don't think so. That would require cutting the same edge twice.

Comment: @Josh Does the algorithm your mentioned work in the above mentioned size 3 cut set, I think it will return this as a valid cut-set since one cannot reach to A from D in edge E2 by BFS.

Comment: @Justin: I guess you're right. You have to generate the suspected cut-edges by actually drawing a 'line' through the graph, not by trying a random subset.

Comment: @Josh : sorry i should have discussed with you, the reason was because when i worked out with your algorithm for the case "in a square graph, when I test for cut-set with any 3 edges, I get the answer as those 3 edges are a valid cut set when it is not the case for eg after removing those 3 edges if i want traverse through bfs to the counterpart node, I cannot which suggest that it is valid cut set according to the algorithm".

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid cut set if, with that edge subset removed, it's no longer a connected graph.

If you're asking for algorithms, you should be able to start at any node and see if you can reach all other nodes via depth first search.  If so, it's not a valid cut set, if it can't, it's a valid cut set.

Comment: The definition of cut set has nothing to do with connectedness I think, for example consider a triangle graph with V = {a,b,c} and E = {ab,bc,ca}. If edge subset S= {ab,bc} are removed then we get ac left which is still connected but S is still a valid cutset since it partitions the G into two vertex subsets {b} and {a,c}

Comment: @Justin: Actually, this isn't correct. It doesn't partition G into two vertex subsets. You can get from {b} to {a} through {ab} (which is still in the subset). You can also get from {b} to {c} through {ac}. Also, [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) and you will see that the definition indeed does involve partitioning into disjoint subsets.