# Find cut set in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, cut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm: for G = (V,E), how to determine if the set of edges(e belong to E) is a valid cut set of a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768329/algorithm-for-g-v-e-how-to-determine-if-the-set-of-edgese-belong-to-e-is)

A subset S, of edges of a graph G = (V,E), how can one check whether it is a **valid cut-set** of the graph or not? 
Note: A cut is a partition of the vertices of a graph into two disjoint subsets. So, cut-set of the cut is the set of edges whose end points are in different subsets of the partition. I am interested to find an algorithm for this problem

Comment: @Moron : That previous algorithm doesnot work for all cases. I have explained in that post that the algorithm will return 3 edges of a square as a valid cutset when it is not.

Comment: Then why have you accepted an answer there? Unaccept it, edit the question saying why the answers don't work, and comment on the answer which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you want to determine whether there exists a labeling V -> {0, 1} such that edges in S have endpoints with different labels, and edges in E - S have endpoints with identical labels. Such a labeling, if it exists, always can be constructed by the following procedure.

Traverse G (say depth-first, but it doesn't really matter). Label traversal roots arbitrarily. Every time you process an edge e from a labeled node u to some other node v, label v with u's label if e not in S and the opposite of u's label if e in S. If v already has a different label, then S is not a cut-set. Otherwise, if the traversal finishes without incident, then S is a cut-set.